# Multiplying a string, a blank space, by zero, still provides a blank space

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project to print out a hill, triangle, and hourglass that are created from asterisks (*). Below is the code that I'm currently using, which correctly prints out the hill, but the triangle and hourglass both have an extra space on each line, despite the first iteration of the while loop multiplying by zero.

```
oddn = int(input("Enter an odd number width: "))
oddn2 = oddn
oddn3 = oddn
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
h = 1
g = 0

print("Hill:")
while oddn >= x:
    print("*" * x )
    x = x+2

print("Triangle:")
while (oddn * 7)+10 >= y:
    ynum = int(oddn/2)
    print(" " * ynum,"*" * y)
    y = y + 2
    oddn = oddn - 2

print("Hourglass:")
while oddn2 >= z:
    print(" " * g,"*" * oddn2)
    oddn2 = oddn2-2
    g = g + 1

while (oddn3 * 7)+10 >= h:
    ynum2 = int(oddn3/2)
    print(" " * ynum2,"*" * h)
    h = h + 2
    oddn3 = oddn3 - 2
```

The current result is listed below.

```
Enter an odd number width: 13
Hill:
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
Triangle:
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
Hourglass:
 *************
  ***********
   *********
    *******
     *****
      ***
       *
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
```

So, as you can see from the result. The hill has no extra spaces along the left side, but the triangle and hourglass do. It may just be an error in my logic, but I've tried correcting it and have yet to find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you provide multiple arguments to `print`, it puts a space between them. That's all that is happening. Empty string, space, your asterisks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is inserting a space between the terms (this is the default for `print`)

```
print(" " * ynum, "*" * y)
```

You can use

```
print(" " * ynum, "*" * y, sep="")
```

or concatenate the strings

```
print(" " * ynum + "*" * y)
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thank you for the prompt answer!